# Creating static instance of MainActivity containing BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, static, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to create a static instance of MainActivity that contains BottomNavigationView but this is always giving warning. I know that placing android context classes in static fields cause memory leak but I am getting this warning only when I am using BottomNavigationView. I don't understand why this warning is not showing without BottomNavigationView and what will be the best way to remove this warning?

Warning message :

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static
>   reference to `MainActivity` which has field `bottomNav` pointing to
>   `BottomNavigationView`); this is a memory leak (and also breaks
>   Instant Run)

My code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav;
    ImageView rootIndicator;
    ...
    ...
}

public class Utils {
    public static MainActivity activity;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever find yourself in a situation where you're thinking of saving a static reference to an Activity like you are now, then rethink your entire design, because you should NEVER EVER do that, and it'll only cause even more problems in the future.

If you tell us what you're trying to do, we might be able to help you in a better way.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I couldn't find any other way to solve this. Actually, I have created a static method to get some info about installed applications using **PackageManager** class and to use **PackageManager** class activity context is required so I am passing the MainActivity context by saving it as a static reference. If there is another way to handle this, then let me know please.